# Large Numeric Value Conversion issue

Tags: string, numeric

I have a large text string number (20 characters, no decimals) that needs to be converted to a number.  I tried Convert.ToInt64 but the value is too large.  What is the best conversion method for a number this large?  And, what is the actual max value for Convert.ToInt64()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) supports numbers from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

You can go larger using [UInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx) (to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615).

If you need bigger than that, the best option is to use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), with [BigInteger.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tryparse.aspx) instead of Convert.ToXXX.  BigInteger supports arbitrarily large integer values, so the size can be as large as needed.

Comment: @MikeTWebb: It's ideal for this - just realize it's .NET 4 (don't know if that matters for you).  If you're .NET 2/3.5, you'll need a custom BigInteger class, like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BigInteger_Library.aspx

Comment: @Reed....yeah, we are using .Net 3.5 so I need to implement that class. Sweet article. Thanks again